# how to skip all single- and multi-line comments in a Parse::RecDescent parser

Tags: perl, parsing, parse-recdescent

In Parse::RecDescent, how do I effectively ignore C++/Java style comments? This includes single-line ('//' until the end of the line) and multi-line (/*everything between here*/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<skip>` defines what the parser considers whitespace.

```
parse: <skip: qr{(?xs:
          (?: \s+                       # Whitespace
          |   /[*] (?:(?![*]/).)* [*]/  # Inline comment
          |   // [^\n]* \n?             # End of line comment
          )
       )*}>
       main_rule
       /\Z/
       { $item[2] }
```

Unlike Nate Glenn's solution, mine

- Doesn't set a global variable affecting all parsers.
- Doesn't use needless captures.
- Doesn't use the non-greedy modifier. (He used the non-greedy modifier to make sure certain characters aren't matched at certain spots, but the non-greedy modifier doesn't guarantee that.)

---

Note: `(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `(?:STRING)` as `[^CHAR]` is to `CHAR`.

Comment: Thanks! I had an answer but hoped for an improvement.

Comment: oh, I didn't realise it your own question you were answering! haha! Honestly, the answer was pretty good. 1) If you want to use $Parse::RecDescent::skip, just use `local` to limit the change to when the grammar is compiled. 2) The speed loss  will be negligible, considering how slow PRD is. 3) I'm mostly being safe. It may or may not be a problem depending on how PRD uses the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the the value of `$Parse::RecDescent::skip`. By default, Parse::RecDescent skips all white space. If you set this variable to a regex matching whitespace and comments, you can skip them. Use this:

```
$Parse::RecDescent::skip = 
    qr{
        (
            \s+                 #whitespace
                |               #or
            /[*] .*? [*]/ \s*   #a multiline comment
                |               #or
            //.*?$               #a single line comment
        )*                      #zero or more

    }mxs;
# m allows '$' to match a newline, x allows regex comments/whitespace, 
# s allows '.' to match newlines.
```

Comment: I think this still suffers from the issue of something that looks like a C-style comment being embedded in a single line comment: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=77702

Comment: @DavidO, No, there's an implied `\G` here.

Comment: @ikegami, Nice.  That will do it. :)